# External PNG graphic not displaying (Geoserver 2.13)

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have recently upgraded from Geoserver 2.11.0 to 2.13.1 and have found my external graphics for point layers are not displaying (they revert to a default grey symbol).

Is there anything wrong in my code, or has anything changed between 2.11 and 2.13 which might be causing problems? Inaccessibility problems for Geoserver to online resources?

An example of my xml is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>cctv_cameras</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>cctv_cameras</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://maps.runnymede.gov.uk/website/maps/png/community/cctv_cameras.png"/>
                <se:Format>image/png</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on my local machine with 2.13.0, but does fail with 2.13.1, I've filed a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8773).

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I cannot remember setting any firewall related for my previous Geoserver installation, would the log files perhaps indicate any problems?

Comment: not sure, can you try to fetch the image using curl or wget from the command line on the server machine?

Comment: Not really something I have any knowledge in unfortunately, but the fact that it does work must mean it is a server connection related issue, just to work out exactly what that problem is and why it would have changed from the migration of 2.11 to 2.13!

Comment: fetch wget from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm and then try wget http://maps.runnymede.gov.uk/website/maps/png/community/cctv_cameras.png

Comment: so probably not firewall, can't think of anything else tbh - turn logging upto geotools and try again, maybe something will show up in the log